# Browsers delaying 5 seconds before attempting first dns query

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser, internet-explorer

I have a fresh OS install with Firefox.
When i open Firefox the homepage (google) takes 5-8 seconds to load. 
All subsequent pages load instantly.

I loaded Wireshark to check if its the DNS server taking a long time to respond but it isn't.

1. Launch Firefox
2. Loading circle on the tab circles anti clockwise for 5-8 seconds. Wireshark shows no network activity during this period.
3. After the delay the loading circle changes to circle clockwise. Wireshark shows the DNS query and response.
4. Web page loads.

Ive disable all plugins but it has made no difference.

I'm running McAfee antivirus.
Internet Explorer shows the same issue. 
Chrome shows the issue but with a slightly shorter delay.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable McAfee AV and test if the problem still exist.
Also be sure that you do not have a home page configured in browser, just use blank page as home page.

Comment: Its a work laptop with McAfee locked down. I cant disable it. I tried setting it to a blank page, the problem remains when i try and go to a site.

Comment: Please do not add "ciao ryder" in all your answers. See [What is the policy on signatures and links in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52486)